# creating a tabbed UIviews with tableviews similar to Iphones music player

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am working on the IOS app that has a tabbed UIview with each tab having its own table view.
lets say its similar to Iphones music player. what i am not able to figure out is how to use use two tableviews in same uiview. i need to show the songs in both grouped and plain Uitable style depending upon how the songsviewcontroller is called. if its called through artistViewController then the tableview should be PLAIN else it should be GROPUED.
I have tried to do it by hiding one tableview at a time but it did not work out. also I am not sure if it is the good thing to use two tableviews (which shows same data and all the actions will be same too). Is it possible to customize the grouped tableview to appear as plain or is there any other ways that I can follow please help mw put here. any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Check out `UITabViewController`.

Comment: Can you show your required image(screenshot)

Comment: did you try with anything??? if yes can you share the same..???

Comment: I think many doors will open for you if you simply drag in a `UITabViewController` into a storyboard. ;)

Answer (score 1):

UITab based Application : Use UITabbarController on click on each tab load Sepearate Views , you do this in Windows.xib file .add Corresponding class to views and Connect them, then Load Different Music Files in Different Class using UITableView on didselectrow method of UITableView play particular Selected Music FILE.